# ADB Connect To Android TV (Sanyo Android TV, Model-SWTV, OS- Android Pie 9.0)

Tags: android, debugging, usb, adb, television

Im Unable to connect to Android TV, I followed the below steps, but still unable to do.

Tried Connecting the TV with my PC using USB Male-Male data cable and entered below commands

1.**ping 192.168.1.16**

Res: 
Pinging 192.168.1.16 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 192.168.1.16: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64

Reply from 192.168.1.16: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64

Reply from 192.168.1.16: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=64

Reply from 192.168.1.16: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.16:

```
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:

```
Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 9ms, Average = 5ms
```

2. **adb tcpip 5555** (To set the port)

Res:
error: no devices/emulators found

3. Tried  **adb kill-server** and **adb start-server**, then did the above process again, still same response
4. **adb connect 192.168.1.16:5555**

Res:
cannot connect to 192.168.1.16:5555: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)

Tried many steps referring multiple links, still no progress.

Im unable to identify the problem. Device is getting pinged but unable to connect. All scenarios tested in the same network

Comment: is adb over wifi available in TV options?

Comment: No, its not available in the TV options

Comment: which Android TV device do you use? my FireTV Stick 4K supports adb over wifi and over LAN out of the box.

Comment: I'm also using Android Stick, which works perfectly. Issue is with the Android Sanyo TV as mentioned in the title.

Comment: I can't find any TV via google. do you have a support homepage link?

Comment: Its a google certified Android TV . Support link :- https://www.sanyoappliance.in/product-support/

I contacted them using chat and email two days ago, still no response.

Comment: I mean a page with product information, PDFs with version history and operation manual

Comment: U mean this one : https://www.sanyoappliance.in/43-inch-android-tv-metallic-xt-43a081u/#specification